# this.setState not overwriting old state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to overwrite some an error label that I'm storing in state, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is not overwriting the key i'm providing it:

```
if(this.state.viewState === 'STEP_1') {
  if (!this.isValidAmount(totalAmountPaid.value)) {
    totalAmountPaid.errorLabel = 'Incorrect Amount';
    this.setState({
      totalAmountPaid,
      errorLabel: 'invalid or missing total amount'
    });
    return;
  };

  if (!this.isValidAmount(amountToBeClaimed.value)) {
    amountToBeClaimed.errorLabel = 'Incorrect Amount';
    console.log('invalidClaimAmount');
    this.setState({
      amountToBeClaimed,
      errorLabel: 'invalid or missing claim amount'
    });
    return;
  };

  if(amountToBeClaimed.value > totalAmountPaid.value) {
    this.setState({ errorLabel: 'claims cannot be greater than total amount paid' });
    return;
  };

  this.setState({ ...this.state, errorLabel: 'asdads' })
};
```

all the setState calls work, except for the last one

`this.setState({ ...this.state, errorLabel: 'asdads' })`

any help appreciated!

***EDIT***
the setState works if I add a return statement to the end of it, but of course, won't let me proceed

```
if(this.state.viewState === 'STEP_1') {
  if (!this.isValidAmount(totalAmountPaid.value)) {
    totalAmountPaid.errorLabel = 'Incorrect Amount';
    this.setState({
      totalAmountPaid,
      errorLabel: 'invalid or missing total amount'
    });
    return;
  };

  if (!this.isValidAmount(amountToBeClaimed.value)) {
    amountToBeClaimed.errorLabel = 'Incorrect Amount';
    console.log('invalidClaimAmount');
    this.setState({
      amountToBeClaimed,
      errorLabel: 'invalid or missing claim amount'
    });
    return;
  };

  if(amountToBeClaimed.value > totalAmountPaid.value) {
    console.log('in amount greater than total if')
    this.setState({ errorLabel: 'claims cannot be greater than total amount paid' });
    return;
  };

  this.setState({ ...this.state, errorLabel: '' });
  return;
};
```

*** CODE SNIPPET in its entirety ***

```
  goToNext = () => {
const { totalAmountPaid, amountToBeClaimed } = this.state.inputs;

if(this.state.viewState === 'ADD_RECEIPT' && this.state.receiptedAdded === true) {
  console.log('in add receipt if')
  let newState = this.state;
  this.setState({
    ...newState,
    viewState: 'STEP_2',
    header: 'Enter Item Details',
    subHeader: "For each item we'll need further information.",
    isFormCompleted: {
      STEP_1: true,
      STEP_2: false
    },
    errorLabel: 'sdadasds'
  }, () => this.saveClaim('STEP_1'));
} else if (this.state.viewState === 'ADD_RECEIPT' && this.state.receiptedAdded === false) {
  this.selectReceipt();
};

if(this.state.viewState === 'STEP_1') {
  if (!this.isValidAmount(totalAmountPaid.value)) {
    totalAmountPaid.errorLabel = 'Incorrect Amount';
    this.setState({
      totalAmountPaid,
      errorLabel: 'invalid or missing total amount'
    });
    return;
  };

  if (!this.isValidAmount(amountToBeClaimed.value)) {
    amountToBeClaimed.errorLabel = 'Incorrect Amount';
    console.log('invalidClaimAmount');
    this.setState({
      amountToBeClaimed,
      errorLabel: 'invalid or missing claim amount'
    });
    return;
  };

  if(amountToBeClaimed.value > totalAmountPaid.value) {
    console.log('in amount greater than total if')
    this.setState({ errorLabel: 'claims cannot be greater than total amount paid' });
    return;
  };

  // //doesnt work????
  // if(amountToBeClaimed.value > this.props.accountBalance) {
  //   this.setState({ errorLabel: 'claims cannot be greater than total account balance' });
  //   return;
  // };

  this.setState({ errorLabel: '' });
};

if(this.state.viewState === 'STEP_2') {
  console.log('in step 2 if');
  if(this.state.inputs.itemOneMajorCategory.value === '') {
    this.setState({ errorLabel: 'Please choose an item category' });
    return;
  };
  if(this.state.inputs.itemOneDocumentaryEvidence.value === '') {
    this.setState({ errorLabel: 'Please provide documentary evidence' });
    return;
  };
  this.setState({ errorLabel: '' });
};

switch (this.state.viewState) {
  case 'STEP_1': 
    let newState = this.state;
    newState.inputs.numberOfItems.value = 1; //for Stage we are doing one item only
      const item = `item${inWords(newState.inputs.numberOfItems.value, 'startCase')}`;
      newState.inputs[`${item}PersonName`] = {
        type: 'generic',
        displayValue: this.props.personFullName,
        value: this.props.personGuid
      };
      newState.inputs[`${item}MajorCategory`] = {
        //optional: true,
        type: 'generic',
        value: '',
        displayValue: '',
        claimCategoryType: ''
      };
      newState.inputs[`${item}ClaimHealthItemGuid`] = {
        optional: true,
        type: 'generic',
        value: '',
        displayValue: '',
      };
      newState.inputs[`${item}AmountPaid`] = {
        //optional: true,
        type: 'generic',
        value: '$',
        formatter: 'currency-new'
      };
      newState.inputs[`${item}DocumentaryEvidence`] = {
        optional: true,
        type: 'generic',
        value: '',
        displayValue: 'Documentary Evidence',
        rightImage: Images.addReceipt
      };
    this.setState({
      ...newState,
      viewState: 'ADD_RECEIPT',
      header: 'Enter Item Details',
      subHeader: "For each item we'll need further information.",
      isFormCompleted: {
        STEP_1: true,
        STEP_2: false
      },
      errorState: false,
    }, () => this.saveClaim('STEP_1'));
    break;
  case 'STEP_2':
    if (!this.hasUserSelectedCheckbox) {
      return;
    }
    /*this.setState({
      viewState: 'STEP_3',
      header: 'Review',
      subHeader: 'If all looks good, submit for adjudication.',
      isFormCompleted: {
        STEP_1: true,
        STEP_2: true
      }
    });*/
    this.saveClaim('STEP_2');
    break;
  case 'STEP_3':
    if (!this.hasUserSelectedCheckbox) {
      return;
    }
    this.saveClaim('STEP_3');
    Actions.claimSubmissionEnd({inputs: this.state.inputs});
    break;
  case 'STEP_4':  
    if (!this.hasUserSelectedCheckbox) {
      return;
    }
    this.saveClaim('STEP_4');
    Actions.claimSubmissionEnd({inputs: this.state.inputs});
    break;
}
```

};

Comment: If any of the first three conditionals are true, the last set state call will not run. This is because of the return statements in the other conditionals. I assume you are aware of this, but I want to make sure you are aware this may be the problem.

Comment: Did you try to firstly declare the object with the errorlabel set, then set the spreaded obj, or vise-versa?

Comment: Put a console log before the final setState. Does it log? If not, then your final setState is not being reached.

Comment: I just double checked and it passes all the IF statements.

Comment: Also just to test, it I add a return after the last `this.setState({ ...this.state, errorLabel: 'asdads' })` it indeed changes the state. but it doesn't seem to run anymore If i remove the return

Comment: The fact that the last `return` makes this work makes me think that code, outside of the scope of this if block you've provided, is the root cause. Can you post your entire code for this method?

Comment: added, sorry its a bit long

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this.state to update your state try to use the setState callback instead:

```
this.setState((prevState) => { ...prevState, errorLabel: 'asdads' })
```

Comment: THIS ^^^^

Remember 'setState' is asynchronous, and there may have been multiple requests by the time yours is run.

The '...this.state' statement is saving your initial state and then using that regardless of any state changes in the meantime.